# PrestaShop hook for standard Refund

Tags: prestashop

what hooks should be used for standard refund in prestaShop?

i used hookActionOrderSlipAdd in partial refund and works good , but got stuck with standard refund

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using **actionOrderStatusPostUpdate** hook and check if the order status is set to any on the one to be considered as refunded (usually *PS_OS_CANCELED* / *PS_OS_REFUNDED* in Configuration table).